# How do you bring back the object properties console?

Tags: interface

This has eluded and frustrated me for too long.

After adding objects like a Sapling or a gear you get a panel inside the tools menu-bar with options to control the object that you just added.

[image: Sapling image]

If you select another object, make changes in the same object(rotate, scale, etc.) or click anywhere in the viewport, the panel disappears. I've never been able to find it once it's gone. I've been trying to follow this tutorial and this happened multiple times and each time I have to start over. So,

**Where is the panel and how do you get it panel back?**